# Cohomologies of Galois group of field extension

Tags: galois-theory, homological-algebra

Let $k\subset K$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G=\text{Aut}_k\,K$. How to prove that $H_i(G,K)=H^i(G,K)=0$ for all $i>0$?